# Select the top 1 row from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that lists the versions of software that are installed:

```
id  | userid | version | datetime
----+--------+---------+------------------------
111 | 75     | 10075   | 2013-03-12 13:40:58.770
112 | 75     | 10079   | 2013-03-12 13:41:01.583
113 | 78     | 10065   | 2013-03-12 14:18:24.463
114 | 78     | 10079   | 2013-03-12 14:22:20.437
115 | 78     | 10079   | 2013-03-12 14:24:01.830
116 | 78     | 10080   | 2013-03-12 14:24:06.893
117 | 74     | 10080   | 2013-03-12 15:31:42.797
118 | 75     | 10079   | 2013-03-13 07:03:56.157
119 | 75     | 10080   | 2013-03-13 07:05:23.137
120 | 65     | 10080   | 2013-03-13 07:24:33.323
121 | 68     | 10080   | 2013-03-13 08:03:24.247
122 | 71     | 10080   | 2013-03-13 08:20:16.173
123 | 78     | 10080   | 2013-03-13 08:28:25.487
124 | 56     | 10080   | 2013-03-13 08:49:44.503
```

I would like to display all fields of one record from each `userid` but only the highest version (also version is a `varchar`).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but **not** a database product. Lots of things are highly vendor-specific - so it would be really helpful to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was trying to figure out how to format it when you edited it. The version is SQL server 12

Comment: How about ties, for example id 116/123?

Comment: Joachim - I have not really thought of that. I guess the highest date would be needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not specifying how you want ties handled, but this will do it if you want the duplicates displayed;

```
SELECT a.* FROM MyTable a
LEFT JOIN MyTable b
  ON a.userid=b.userid
 AND CAST(a.version AS INT) < CAST(b.version AS INT)
WHERE b.version IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1da4/4).

If you want to eliminate duplicates and if they exist pick the newest of them, you'll have to extend the query somewhat;

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, CAST(version AS INT) num_version FROM MyTable)
SELECT a.id, a.userid, a.version, a.datetime 
FROM cte a LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON a.userid=b.userid
 AND (a.num_version < b.num_version OR 
     (a.num_version = b.num_version AND a.[datetime]<b.[datetime]))
WHERE b.version IS NULL
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3892c/3).

Comment: Thanks Joachim - I will be using your second example here - Paul

Comment: @Easty Edited the query slightly, eliminated some casts with a common table expresion to make it easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 8):

If you use SQL-Server (minimum 2005) you can use a `CTE` with the `ROW_NUMBER` function. You can use `CAST` for version to get the correct order:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                userid, 
                version, 
                datetime, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY userid 
                    ORDER BY Cast(version AS INT) DESC) rn 
         FROM   [dbo].[table]) 
SELECT id, 
       userid, 
       version, 
       datetime 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1 
ORDER BY userid
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9639/4/0)

[`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) returns always one record even if there are multiple users with the same (top) version. If you want to return all "top-version-user-records", you have to replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `DENSE_RANK()` which I've never seen before :)

Comment: @LouisBliss CTE's can be very fast. But if the table is large, then this approach can actually be fairly non-performant as the windowing function needs to consider the enter record set. Cross apply tends to be my preferred approach for any system of scale.

Answer (score 6):

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  id, userid, version, datetime,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userID
                                ORDER BY version DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
SELECT id, userid, version, datetime
FROM    records
WHERE   RN =1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/febfe/1)

Comment: the reason why I deleted this answer is because at first you haven't mentioned the database server you are using. by the way this works on sql server 2005 and above `:)`

Comment: Version is a varchar ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this may solve your problem :

```
 SELECT id,
       userid,
       Version,
       datetime FROM (
           SELECT id,
                  userid,
                  Version,
                  datetime , 
                  DENSE_Rank() over (Partition BY id order by datetime asc) AS Rankk
           FROM [dbo].[table]) RS 
WHERE Rankk<2
```

I used RANK function for ur requirement....

Answer (score 0):

```
select l.* from the_table l
left outer join the_table r
on l.userid = r.userid and l.version < r.version
where r.version is null
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will display what you want and is great for performance!

```
select * from the_table t where cast([version] as int) = 
(select max(cast([version] as int)) from the_table where userid = t.userid)
```

Comment: An explanation of your code would be beneficial not only to the asker but to future people who may stumble across this searching for a solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If my experience tuning has taught me anything, generalities are bad bad bad.

BUT, If the table your getting the `Top X` from is large (i.e. hundreds of thousands or millions). `CROSS APPLY` is almost universally the best. In fact, if you benchmark it, cross apply performs **consistently & admirably** at smaller scales as well (in the tens of thousands) And ever covers the **with ties** potential requirement.

Something like:

```
select
    id
    ,userid
    ,version
    ,datetime
from
    TheTable t
cross apply
(
    select top 1 --with ties
        id
    from
        TheTable
    where
        userid = t.userid
    order by
        datetime desc
)
```