# SQL-find the ratings with the max complete_date with group by

Tags: sql, group-by

Please run the DDL and DML on sqlfiddle. I am trying to come up with a query to find the ratings of the FID that has the max complete_date

DDL:

```
create table crr (rating varchar(255), FID int, complete_date varchar(255));
```

DML:

```
insert into crr values ('low', 182, '2021/11/1'),('medium', 182,'2022/6/14'), ('medium', 369,'2021/9/1')
, ('medium', 369,'2021/11/9'), ('medium', 429,'2021/4/5'), ('medium', 429,'2021/4/6'),('high', 429,'2022/12/5');
```

my query is:

```
Select c.fid, rating, c.complete_date 
From crr c
Inner Join (
Select fid, Max(complete_date)as d 
From crr
Group By fid)A;
On c.fid=A.fid and c.complete_date=d;
```

It is not returning what I wanted.
Ideal output would be:

- rating FID complete_date
- medium 182 2022/6/14
- medium 369 2021/11/9
- high   429 2022/12/5

It should be easy-peasy, please advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select the top 1 row from each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380718/select-the-top-1-row-from-each-group)

Comment: what is exactly what you need? what is the logic to get the expected results shown?

Comment: Your query works after the fix mentioned in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
select * from crr a
where complete_date = (select max(complete_date) from crr b where b.fid=a.fid)
order by fid
```

I changed completed_date to date, with varchar I was having different results

```
create  table crr (rating varchar(255), FID int, complete_date date);

insert into crr values ('low', 182, '2021/11/1'),('medium', 182,'2022/6/14'), ('medium', 369,'2021/9/1')
, ('medium', 369,'2021/11/9'), ('medium', 429,'2021/4/5'), ('medium', 429,'2021/4/6'),('high', 429,'2022/12/5');
```

Comment: I guess your way works.

Comment: Yes, convert the string to date.

Comment: consider what I mentioned. Date stored as varchar brings issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select rating, c.fid, c.complete_date 
From crr c
Inner Join (
Select fid, Max(complete_date) as d
From crr
Group By fid) as A On c.fid=A.fid and c.complete_date=A.d;
```

Date is a string, then sorting will be in lexicographic order

Comment: You are right. That's why 2021/9/1>2021/11/1. How can we convert string to date in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Come to think of it.
This is what I came up with

```
select rating, fid, complete_date from (
select *, row_number() over(partition by FID order by complete_date desc)as n
from crr)A
where A.n=1
```